# Organizing Google sheets data range into single column

Tags: google-sheets

[image: translating data range into single column]

Looking for a way to populate a single column with all information contained within a range of cells. Let's say I want to take all of the data (A1:F12 , Sheet1) highlighted in the example picture and put it into a single column in the Sheet2 tab — is this possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- CONCATENATE everything with a chicken
- SPLIT the chicken and TRANSPOSE

  ```
  =ARRAYFORMULA(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(A1:F12&""),"")))
  ```

Comment: +1 for the chicken, but does not work with large data sets due to concatenate's 50,000 char limit

Comment: You can also use anything else other than a chicken, in case anybody is confused with not having the emoji available. For example: =ArrayFormula(transpose(split(concatenate(A1:F12&char(9)),char(9))))

Answer (score 7):

So, I was looking for an answer to this and found this function that solve seamlessly this problem.

```
=FILTER(FLATTEN(range), FLATTEN(range)<>"")
```

With this you can solve your problem.

PS: I add this answer because with this you will not have the 50,000 char limit problem.

Comment: Thanks @jóni for the clean approach suggested. Worked like a charm.